# Error converting value to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List` in my json

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am having problem in converting JSON to object in C#. I want to know that what's wrong with my json or object structure? Why its failing?

My JSON is:

```
[ { "added_on" : "10-03-2014",
    "country" : "INDIA",
    "crew" : "{\"Actor1\": \"Kangana\", \"Actor2\":\"Lisa Haydon\"}\r\n",
    "fb_link" : "https://www.facebook.com/Queenthefilm",
    "genre" : "DRAMA",
    "id" : 1,
    "image_first_url" : "",
    "image_main_url" : "133avk38CcBfNHsqwr0nzqOa8Db.jpg",
    "image_second_url" : "",
    "name" : "Queen",
    "ratings" : "[{\"type\": \"IMDB\", \"value\": \"9.3\"}, {\"type\": \"TOI\", \"value\": \"4\"}, {\"type\": \"NDTV\", \"value\": \"3\"}]",
    "release_date" : "07-03-2014",
    "release_year" : 2014,
    "storyline" : "A Delhi girl from a traditional family sets out on a solo honeymoon after her marriage gets canceled.",
    "twitter_link" : "https://twitter.com/Queenthefilm",
    "youtube_link" : "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KGC6vl3lzf0"
  } ]
```

My object structure:

```
public class Movie
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string storyline { get; set; }
    public string crew { get; set; }
    public string genre { get; set; }
    public string release_year { get; set; }
    public string release_date { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
    public string youtube_link { get; set; }
    public string fb_link { get; set; }
    public string twitter_link { get; set; }
    public string image_main_url { get; set; }
    public string image_first_url { get; set; }
    public string image_second_url { get; set; }
    public string added_on { get; set; }
    public List<Rating> ratings { get; set; }
}

public class Rating
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

Error:

```
Error converting value "[{"type": "IMDB", "value": "9.3"}, {"type": "TOI", "value": "4"}, {"type": "NDTV", "value": "3"}]" to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[mq.channel.Rating]'. Path '[0].ratings', line 1, position 731.
```

Comment: In encountered this error while using EF Core to de/serialize stringified JSON to/from the DB. EF Core had copied data from a column I expected to be deleted, and the old data did not match the expected format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your JSON doesn't contain an array for the `ratings` property but a string.
It should rather look like

```
[ { "added_on" : "10-03-2014",
    "country" : "INDIA",
    "crew" : "{\"Actor1\": \"Kangana\", \"Actor2\":\"Lisa Haydon\"}\r\n",
    "fb_link" : "https://www.facebook.com/Queenthefilm",
    "genre" : "DRAMA",
    "id" : 1,
    "image_first_url" : "",
    "image_main_url" : "133avk38CcBfNHsqwr0nzqOa8Db.jpg",
    "image_second_url" : "",
    "name" : "Queen",
    "ratings" : [{"type": "IMDB", "value": "9.3"}, {"type": "TOI", "value": "4"}, {"type": "NDTV", "value": "3"}],
    "release_date" : "07-03-2014",
    "release_year" : 2014,
    "storyline" : "A Delhi girl from a traditional family sets out on a solo honeymoon after her marriage gets canceled.",
    "twitter_link" : "https://twitter.com/Queenthefilm",
    "youtube_link" : "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KGC6vl3lzf0"
  } ]
```

in order for the `ratings` property to be analyzed as an array (note that the quotes and escape backslashes are removed)

Answer (score 6):

I met with same problem and i solved with following code

```
YourVariable.Replace("\"[", "[").Replace("]\"", "]").Replace("\\", "");
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to remove the quotes from your `ratings` array property, otherwise it's going to be treated as a string i.e.

```
"ratings": [...]
```