# Returning JArray inside of a JSON object

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I've been developing a simple .Net Core API. Most of my Controllers execute SQL procedures that get the data and return it in the format specified in the model on the C# side. I made a query that takes some dynamic data (TransactionDetails) and puts it into JSON format.

I want to be able to read this field as JSON on the C# side, but cannot get it to work. For now, I have the type set to string. I have tried using 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq' and setting the TransactionDetails field to JArray in the model, but this breaks the Authorization portion of the API for some reason.

Controller:

```
[HttpGet("/api/Customer/GetTransactions/{customerNumber}/{startDate}/{endDate}")]
public async Task<IEnumerable<CustomerTransaction>> GetCustomerTransactions(string customerNumber, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    var custNum = new SqlParameter("@custNum", customerNumber);
    var dateFrom = new SqlParameter("@dateFrom", startDate);
    var dateTo = new SqlParameter("@dateTo", endDate);
    return await context.CustomerTransactions.FromSql("EXEC MyDatabase.dbo.crm_GetCustomerTransactions @custNum, @dateFrom, @dateTo", custNum, dateFrom, dateTo)
    .AsNoTracking()
    .ToArrayAsync();
}
```

Model:

```
public class CustomerTransaction
{
    [Key] public string KwiNumber { get; set; }
    public int StoreNumber { get; set; }
    public int TransactionNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan TransactionTime { get; set; }
    public string TransactionDetails { get; set; }
}
```

Current Response:

```
[
    "kwiNumber":"XXXXXXXXXX",
    "storeNumber":"XXXXXX",
    "transactionNumber":169306,
    "transactionDate":"2014-03-30T00:00:00",
    "transactionTime":"17:21:00",
    "transactionDetails":"[\r\n    {\"StoreNumber\":\"XXXXXX\",\"TransactionNumber\":\"170272\",\"KwiNumber\":\"XXXXXXXXXX\",\"TenDigitUPC\":\"4303677390\",\"TerminalNumber\":\"1\",\"TransactionDate\":\"2014-04-18\",\"TransactionTime\":\"14:27:00\",\"EmployeeNumber\":\"10546\",\"CashierNumber\":\"10546\",\"DiscountReasonCode\":\"0\",\"CouponCode\":\"0\",\"SalesType\":\"R\",\"UnitsSold\":\"2\",\"SalePrice\":\"30.00\",\"StyleNumber\":\"J97922\",\"ClassCode\":\"020\",\"SubClassCode\":\"108\"},\r\n    {\"StoreNumber\":\"XXXXXX\",\"TransactionNumber\":\"170272\",\"KwiNumber\":\"XXXXXXXXXX\",\"TenDigitUPC\":\"4303678979\",\"TerminalNumber\":\"1\",\"TransactionDate\":\"2014-04-18\",\"TransactionTime\":\"14:27:00\",\"EmployeeNumber\":\"10546\",\"CashierNumber\":\"10546\",\"DiscountReasonCode\":\"0\",\"CouponCode\":\"0\",\"SalesType\":\"R\",\"UnitsSold\":\"1\",\"SalePrice\":\"0.00\",\"StyleNumber\":\"D31001\",\"ClassCode\":\"111\",\"SubClassCode\":\"039\"},\r\n    {\"StoreNumber\":\"XXXXXX\",\"TransactionNumber\":\"170272\",\"KwiNumber\":\"XXXXXXXXXX\",\"TenDigitUPC\":\"8193434784\",\"TerminalNumber\":\"1\",\"TransactionDate\":\"2014-04-18\",\"TransactionTime\":\"14:27:00\",\"EmployeeNumber\":\"10546\",\"CashierNumber\":\"10546\",\"DiscountReasonCode\":\"0\",\"CouponCode\":\"0\",\"SalesType\":\"R\",\"UnitsSold\":\"1\",\"SalePrice\":\"8.00\",\"StyleNumber\":\"J96412\",\"ClassCode\":\"020\",\"SubClassCode\":\"108\"}\r\n]"
]
```

Desired Response:

```
[
    "kwiNumber":"XXXXXXXXXX",
    "storeNumber":"XXXXXX",
    "transactionNumber":169306,
    "transactionDate":"2014-03-30T00:00:00",
    "transactionTime":"17:21:00",
    "transactionDetails": [ 
        {
            "StoreNumber":"XXXXXX",
            "TransactionNumber":"169306",
            "KwiNumber":"XXXXXXXXXX",
            "TenDigitUPC":"4303680836",
            "TerminalNumber":"1",
            "TransactionDate":"2014-03-30",
            "TransactionTime":"17:21:00",
            "EmployeeNumber":"2215",
            "CashierNumber":"2215",
            "DiscountReasonCode":"0",
            "CouponCode":"0",
            "SalesType":"R",
            "UnitsSold":"1",
            "SalePrice":"68.00",
            "StyleNumber":"JN7612",
            "ClassCode":"008",
            "SubClassCode":"026"
        }, 
        {
            "StoreNumber":"XXXXXX",
            "TransactionNumber":"169306",
            "KwiNumber":"XXXXXXXXXX",
            "TenDigitUPC":"8193434814",
            "TerminalNumber":"1",
            "TransactionDate":"2014-03-30",
            "TransactionTime":"17:21:00",
            "EmployeeNumber":"2215",
            "CashierNumber":"2215",
            "DiscountReasonCode":"0",
            "CouponCode":"0",
            "SalesType":"R",
            "UnitsSold":"2",
            "SalePrice":"52.00",
            "StyleNumber":"J96442",
            "ClassCode":"020",
            "SubClassCode":"108"
        }
    ]
]
```

How can I read this dynamic JArray in C# and return it as a child JSON element when GetCustomerTransactions is called?

Thanks!

Comment: Why is `TransactionDetails` a string if you want it to be an array?

Comment: I have tried using 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq' and setting the TransactionDetails field to JArray in the model, but this breaks the Authorization portion of the API for some reason, it's just a converter should not break anything to do with AUTH, what happens exactly ?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto -- I tried setting it to JArray (see post).

Comment: But why `JArray`? Why not a normal c# array/list?

Comment: @saj - When I pass my Auth Bearer Token for any API Request, I get "InvalidOperationException: The entity type 'JToken' requires a primary key to be defined". As soon as I switch it back from JArray to string, the error goes away.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto -- .Net is unable to map it to an Array or List because I already have it in JSON format coming from SQL.

Comment: have you tied to convert it with a type like dynamic, as you seem to be using a entity type ? ps:- post your convert code

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto -- I know! Thanks.

Comment: @saj -- I have not tried this and am not too familiar with how to go about that. For now, I'm parsing the string on the front end:       if (val != null && (typeof val['transactionDetails'] === "string")) {
        let parsedTransactions = JSON.parse(val['transactionDetails']);
        this.customerTransactions['transactionDetails'] = parsedTransactions;
      }

Comment: add nuget pkg https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/  then try this var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jsonstr); passing in parsed JSON string

Comment: @brandoncluff, If my answer helped you solve the problem, please mark it as accepted. If not, please specify what didn't work and I'll try to help

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear why the json holds `transactionDetails` as a string, [as it should be an array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22451323/3002584). If it would have been an array, you would have the following classes:

```
public class TransactionDetail
{
    public string StoreNumber { get; set; }
    public string TransactionNumber { get; set; }
    public string KwiNumber { get; set; }
    public string TenDigitUPC { get; set; }
    public string TerminalNumber { get; set; }
    public string TransactionDate { get; set; }
    public string TransactionTime { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeNumber { get; set; }
    public string CashierNumber { get; set; }
    public string DiscountReasonCode { get; set; }
    public string CouponCode { get; set; }
    public string SalesType { get; set; }
    public string UnitsSold { get; set; }
    public string SalePrice { get; set; }
    public string StyleNumber { get; set; }
    public string ClassCode { get; set; }
    public string SubClassCode { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerTransaction
{
    public string kwiNumber { get; set; }
    public string storeNumber { get; set; }
    public int transactionNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime transactionDate { get; set; }
    public string transactionTime { get; set; }
    public List<TransactionDetail> transactionDetails { get; set; }
}
```

and then parsing it would be as simple as:

```
var records = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CustomerTransaction>>(json);
```

However,  if `transactionDetails` can't be changed to an array for some reason, you can do the following:

1. Change `CustomerTransaction` to:

   ```
   public class CustomerTransaction
   {
       public string kwiNumber { get; set; }
       public string storeNumber { get; set; }
       public int transactionNumber { get; set; }
       public DateTime transactionDate { get; set; }
       public string transactionTime { get; set; }

       [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "transactionDetails")]
       public string transactionDetailsRaw { get; set; } 
       [JsonIgnoreAttribute]
       public List<TransactionDetail> transactionDetails { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Parse the json into a `JArray`, iterate each child, and parse `transactionDetails` separately.

Full example program (I used a more minimal version of your json. Fiddle is [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FDAOnz)):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string toParse =
        "[{\r\n    \"kwiNumber\":\"XXXXXXXXXX\",\r\n    \"transactionDetails\" : \"[\\r\\n    {\\\"StoreNumber\\\":\\\"XXXXXX\\\" } \\r\\n]\"}]";
        List<CustomerTransaction> records = new List<CustomerTransaction>();
        JArray parsed = JArray.Parse(toParse);
        foreach(var item in parsed.Children())
        {
            CustomerTransaction customerTransaction = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomerTransaction>(item.ToString());
            customerTransaction.transactionDetails = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TransactionDetail>>(customerTransaction.transactionDetailsRaw);
            records.Add(customerTransaction);
        }

    }

    public class TransactionDetail
    {
        public string StoreNumber { get; set; }
        public string TransactionNumber { get; set; }
        public string KwiNumber { get; set; }
        public string TenDigitUPC { get; set; }
        public string TerminalNumber { get; set; }
        public string TransactionDate { get; set; }
        public string TransactionTime { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeNumber { get; set; }
        public string CashierNumber { get; set; }
        public string DiscountReasonCode { get; set; }
        public string CouponCode { get; set; }
        public string SalesType { get; set; }
        public string UnitsSold { get; set; }
        public string SalePrice { get; set; }
        public string StyleNumber { get; set; }
        public string ClassCode { get; set; }
        public string SubClassCode { get; set; }
    }

    public class CustomerTransaction
    {
        public string kwiNumber { get; set; }
        public string storeNumber { get; set; }
        public int transactionNumber { get; set; }
        public DateTime transactionDate { get; set; }
        public string transactionTime { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "transactionDetails")]
        public string transactionDetailsRaw { get; set; } 
        [JsonIgnoreAttribute]
        public List<TransactionDetail> transactionDetails { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! I got sidetracked by some time-sensitive projects, but should be able to give this implementation a shot soon (and accept it as the correct answer). Thanks!